# Syntax error in Django queryset extra query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

The following contains a syntax error:

```
date = datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=30)
articles = Article.objects.filter(published=True).extra(select = {
  "views" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myapp_readership
    JOIN myapp_article on myapp_readership.which_article_id = myapp_article.id
  WHERE myapp_readership.reader_id = myapp_user.id
  AND myapp_readership.what_time > %s """ % date,
}).order_by("-views")
```

The error being: **syntax error at or near "01"** (where "01" was the datetime object inside extra). It's not much to go on. Can someone point out what's going on?

---

**Background:** The models relating to the above code are:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Readership(models.Model):
    reader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    what_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I wrote the above code because I was trying to get all published articles, sorted by unique readership each article experienced in the last 30 mins. I.e. counting how many distinct (unique) views each published article got in the last half an hour, and then producing a list of articles sorted by these distinct views. My code is missing handling the *'distinct'* part of the requirement - I don't know how to accomplish that here.

Comment: Try wrapping `%s` in quotes (so that is `myapp_readership.what_time > '%s'`). If that helps, consider some other way of building queries - string formatting is the worst (practical) one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never ever use string substitution in an SQL query, whether that is part of an `extra` call or not. You've discovered one reason why not - because values are not quoted properly - but the more important reason is that it leaves you open to SQL injection.

Instead, use the facilities that the db api gives you: in this case, use `select_params`:

```
.extra(
  select={
    "views" : """
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM myapp_readership
        JOIN myapp_article on myapp_readership.which_article_id = myapp_article.id
      WHERE myapp_readership.reader_id = myapp_user.id
      AND myapp_readership.what_time > %s """
    },
    select_params=(date,),
)
```

Also see the note [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra); the `extra` method is deprecated, and the query can certainly be expressed using other ORM methods.